# strange viewport fog unwanted

Tags: 3d-view

What causes this slight circle mist in blender ?
On the left i'm zoomed out a lot so the cube isnt visible anymore you'll see it better.
i'd like to remove it/disable it[image]
its slightly cropped but when you click on the image you should be able to see it.

Comment: If you go to *World" properties is there some "Use Nodes" that you can change or disable?

Comment: Using the Viewport Shading dropdown, try changing the *Background*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to:

*Blender Preferences* > *Themes* > *3D Viewport* > *Theme Space* > *Gradient Colors* > *Background Type*

Set to *Single Color*

[image]

Comment: ahaa its a theme thing i looked at viewport